# CISourceOverCompositing produce different results on device and in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-image

I'm trying to use the `CISourceOverCompositing` filter but I'm hitting some wall.

This is the relevant code. mask is a `UIImage` and images is an array of `UIImage`

```
ci_mask = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: mask.CGImage];
ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions: nil];
compo = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CISourceOverCompositing"];
for(int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
  UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex: i];
  ci_base = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: image.CGImage];
  [compo setDefaults];
  [compo setValue: ci_mask forKey: @"inputImage"];
  [compo setValue: ci_base forKey: @"inputBackgroundImage"];
  result = compo.outputImage;

  CGImageDestinationAddImage(
    dst_ref,
    [ctx createCGImage: result fromRect:result.extent],
    frame_props
  );
}
```

`mask` contains an alpha channel which is correctly applied in the simulator but not on the device. The output only show the mask as-is seemingly without using the alpha channel to blend images.

The almost same code using CoreGraphics API works fine (but then I can't apply other CIFilters)

I'll probably try to use `CIBlendWithMask` but then I'll have to extract the mask and add complexity...

Answer (score 1):

Look for different capitalization in your filenames and the files being specified. They don't have to be the same case to work in the simulator, but they are case sensitive on the device. This has thrown me off many times and if you don't look for it is quite difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the issue and it's a bit tricky. First, to answer Jeshua, both the mask and the base are generated so the path isn't relevant here (but I'll keep that in mind, definitively good to know).

Now for the "solution". When generating the mask I used a combination of CG* calls on a background context (`CGImageCreateWithMask`, ...). Now, it seems that the result of those call gives me a `CGImage` seemingly without alpha channel (`CGImageGetAlphaInfo` returns 0) but... both CoreGraphics APIs on device and in the simulator AND CoreImage APIs but only in the simulator applies the still present alpha channel.

Creating a CGContext with `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` and using `CGContextDrawImage` with `kCGBlendModeSourceOut` (or whatever you need to "hollow out" your image) keeps the alpha channel intact and this works on both the simulator and the device.

I'll file a radar as either the simulator or the device is wrong.